# Changing HTML content of external webpage loaded into a DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to web development.I have loaded an external webpage into my website and i want to manipulate the HTML of that page. I want to hide the button with the id "sharepopup" in the code below. But it is not working. What am I doing wrong

```
<div id="content" >
<object type="type/html" data=http://credihealth.com>           
</object>    
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sharepopup").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the DOM of third party websites. That would be a security risk.

You can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to communicate between **cooperating** websites on different origins (although I don't know if it works when using `<object>` instead of `<iframe>`).

Comment: The asker's iframe content is not from the "same-origin" as javascript being run to modify it, therefore, it cannot directly modify the iframe contents. Check out this question/answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe/364997#364997

Comment: fair enough. Same basic premise, but you're right, sorry about that. :-) I edited my comment so that my incorrect info doesn't throw people off.